# How to remove special characters and stop words in a file using python?

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I am new to python and struggling to make code removing stop words and special characters from a file without using nltk. I tried reading and taking ideas from other questions but none helped me.

Also, I tried installing nltk in PyCharm and importing it

```
import nltk
```

but it says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python2.7, install it from terminal running : `pip install nltk`
Otherwise, for python 3, just run `pip3 install nltk`

If you meet this kind of error

[image]

just run `nltk.download('punkt')`(or whatever you see in the error, here I got punkt) from our python console

You shouldn't see any importError now

Comment: when i run nltk.download() NLTK downloader pop-up but errors says: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

Comment: if you're on mac os, can you see in application some folder named python3.x ? If yes, enter it and click in the file named install certifcate (or so), does it work for you ?

Comment: Oh it worked. Thank you! but how do i use this in PyCharm?

Comment: pleasure. And for the use in pycharm, you don't have anything else to do (pycharm is just your IDE), just import nltk on the top of your file to use in as you did. And if you installed it in a virtualenv or so, don't forget to launch your script from this environment :)  see their [documentation](https://www.nltk.org) to use it well

Comment: I tried importing nltk in my IDE but the result is same: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code you have with the import ? So I can compare to mine